# make all the <table> rows sortable/drag on a page.

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-sortable, sortables

I have a page where there are multiple tables and other tables are added dynamically. I want to apply .Sortable jquery option so user can change the order of the table rows. I have other page pages where i have fixed number of tables or Order list where i have applied the drag and drop sortable option where user can order the items by this type of code.

```
 $("[id*=AuthorGird]").sortable({
                items: 'tr:not(tr:first-child)',
                cursor: 'pointer',
                axis: 'y',
                dropOnEmpty: false, 
            });
```

or like  this when there are fixed number

```
$("#sortableKeyword1,#sortableKeyword2,#sortableKeyword3,#sortableKeyword4").sortable({
......
});
```

Now for this page i tables are added dynamically and i want to add sortable on all the tables.Things i tried but nothing seem to working. Please guide me on correct path.

```
 $("[type=table]").sortable({
                    items: 'tr:not(tr:first-child)',
                    cursor: 'pointer',
                    axis: 'y'
})
```

And

```
 $("input[type=table]").sortable({
```

how can i apply sortable on all the type of table on one page?

Comment: Maybe `$("table").sortable()`? why `input[type=table]`? To be honest i never saw input type be table.

Comment: And for items `items: 'tbody tr'`

Comment: $("table").sortable() did worked for me. I have used similar kind of code for radio button. ` $('input[name="AwardIDRdo1"][value="0"]').prop('checked', true); `  and i tough i can use Type =table. Thanks for pointing this out. Best

Comment: `table` HTML tag is totally different from `radio` button tag. I mean it should be, if its not in your code, you writing too wrong